# Error When Creating UIWebView Programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, exception, uiwebview

I want to create a WebView programmatically. I tried to search Google and the result is I should write these code in my viewDidLoad:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,968,875)];
webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

I did exactly the same and when I run it, I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS with the following Exception messages:

Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

Anyone has any idea what I did wrong with my code? Please reply. I really appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 1):

In any case, you **should not access UI** (animations, alert views, new view controllers etc) **from threads other than Main Thread**. Most likely you init WebView in some kind of selector, that is not main thread.

Try to rebuild your App or use performSelectorOnMainThread.
If You can provide more code I'm willing to help futhermore.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My friend told me yesterday to add
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
...
}
to the code where i create the WebView and it works perfectly..